# What is the best chart to visualize this data (number of users, number of users gained, number of users lost)

Tags: charts, visualization, data-visualization

I want to represent some data visually, using a visualization component.
Now I want to represent this situation in a visual way: 
Suppose I have an web application. I want to get an overview in a visual way about how users are reacting to it.

Say:

- in Day1 I have 2 users: u1, u2
- in Day2 I have 2 users: u1, u2
- In Day3 I have 3 users: u3, u4

It is useless to draw a line chart here. Because I'll be seeing a constant line. Although I have lost 2 users and gained 2 users in Day3.

How to represent this data in a chart? The chart should give me an idea about: -

- total number of users
- number of users lost
- number of users gained.

Comment: Not quite dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/what-is-the-best-plotting-library-for-python . Also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plotting+library

Comment: The question is actually just about which type of visualization to use, not what library/language to create one with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: after further thinking, I think this is the best.  The other options I listed seem inadequate.

A grouped bar chart like this:
[Grouped bar chart http://www.virtuallywiredinc.com/3D_Charts/ASPNET.JPG](http://www.virtuallywiredinc.com/3D_Charts/ASPNET.JPG)

With one bar for each category, number on Y axis and date on X axis.

(Image from Google search, unknown copyright)

Comment: I liked Greg's solution also. Accepting this as the answer because, it is easier to compare the values visually in grouped chart.

Answer (score 3):

Stacked bar.  Top of the stack is new users in a day.  It sits on top of (total users at day start - new users), which sits on the x-axis.  Dipping below the x-axis is users lost.  Thus the height above the x-axis is the actual number of users that day, and the total height of the bar (above and below the x-axis) is the total number of users before your users were lost.

Answer (score 2):

I like Adam Bellaire's suggestion.  I just threw together this little sketch of what that might look like.  (I prefer simple lines instead of thick bars).  After sketching it out, I'm not sure how much I like it.  Any thoughts?

[image: my sketch of Adam Bellaire's suggestion]

Comment: This makes me wonder if a stacked area version of your chart would be more effective.

Comment: @Selene -- Yeah, I agree with you.  Maybe something like this chart, which was recently in the New York Times?  http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2009/07/31/business/20080801-metrics-graphic.html

Comment: The problem with the stacked charts is that you do not instantly see one of the values.  I still think a grouped bar approach is best for this.

Comment: @Adam -- the only value that you don't see is the number of new users, in the case that there are no new users.  So I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Greg, no I mean the stacked bar as described simply places one set of values on top of the other.  So to actually count new users, you need to take the total height and subtract the value of users at the start.  To get total number of users at the end of a day, take the value above the axis and subtract the value below the axis.

It is helpful for looking at relative values not actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a line for the users in a day and a bar for the number of new users/total users.